# Erro 1153 do MySQL: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Tags: mysql

Ao tentar importar pela linha de comando uma base de dados a partir de um *dump* com 1.2GB, ocorreu o seguinte erro:

> ERROR 1153 (08S01) at line 727: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

O comando que estou usando para a importação é:

```
mysql -u usuario -p banco < dump.sql
```

Como resolver isso?

Comment: O teu `dump.sql` tinha as consultas de `INSERT` com limite de X `rows` ? Ou um `INSERT` tratava de todas as `ROWS` ?

Comment: Tenho um `INSERT` com vários `VALUES` por tabela (isso foi gerado pelo *mysqldump*). Como vejo se há limite de X rows?

Comment: Quando são tabelas muito grandes, os `INSERT` vão-se repetindo de 50 em 50 `rows` por exemplo. Caso contrário um `INSERT` com vários `VALUES` ultrapassa os limites do pacote. Vários `INSERT` dá pacotes mais pequenos e torna-se mais viável.

Comment: Meu arquivo está difícil de consultar por ser tão grande, mas descobri agora que de fato há vários `INSERT`s por tabela. Não sei dizer quantas linhas por `INSERT`. Mesmo assim estava dando o erro até eu aumentar o max_allowed_packet.

Comment: Eu faço uso do [gVim](http://www.vim.org/download.php) para consultar arquivos texto maiores que 1GB. Até agora conseguir abrir um de 8GB sem problemas em Linux :)

Comment: Eu estou usando o vim também, no Mac, mas ao fazer rolamento às vezes ele pula uma "tela" inteira (acho que é porque a linha é grande demais).

Comment: Essas linhas mega são provavelmente o motivo pelo qual o limite do pacote é ultrapassado!

Comment: Também acho, mas a solução que postei abaixo resolveu (o que faz sentido). Se você souber de uma solução na outra ponta, que force o `mysqldump` a gerar pacotes menores, seria muito útil!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Encontrei a resposta numa [resposta de Michael Pryor no Stack Overflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93128/mysql-error-1153-got-a-packet-bigger-than-max-allowed-packet-bytes).

Segundo ele, é necessário alterar uma configuração do MySQL, e passar um parâmetro a mais para o *client* na linha de comando, definindo um calor alto para `max_allowed_packet` (ele usa `100M`).

**Alteração no `my.cnf`** (ou my.ini em Windows)

```
max_allowed_packet=100M
```

Como alternativa, pode-se rodar os seguintes comandos no servidor:

```
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```

**Alteração na chamada ao client**

```
mysql --max_allowed_packet=100M -u usuario -p banco < dump.sql
```

(Reiniciei o servidor antes de chamar o client.)