# Erro ao gravar no mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde a todos...

Gostaria de saber o motivo do erro no array abaixo...

Isso acontece qdo vou passar ele para gravar no banco de dados

```
Array
(
[arquivo] => Array
    (
        [name] => Tabloide Março 2018.pdf
        [type] => application/pdf
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpJnYMFn
        [error] => 0
        [size] => 1956251
    )

)
```

**Segue o codigo**

```
/* Importa o arquivo onde a função de upload está implementada */
$arquivo        = $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"]; 
$tamanho        = $_FILES["arquivo"]["size"];
$tipo           = $_FILES["arquivo"]["type"];
$nome           = $_FILES["arquivo"]["name"];
$interessado    = $_POST["nome"];
$email          = $_POST["email"];
$cpf            = $_POST["cpf"];
$telefone       = $_POST["telefone"];
$cidade         = $_POST["cidade"];
$interesse      = $_POST["interesse"];
$mensagem       = $_POST["msg"];

if ($arquivo != "none") {
 $fp = fopen($arquivo, "rb");
 $conteudo = fread($fp, $tamanho);
 $conteudo = addslashes($conteudo);
 fclose($fp); 

 $qry = "INSERT INTO trabalhe (id, nome, email, cpf, telefone, cidade, 
 interesse, mensagem, nome_arquivo, arquivo, tipo) VALUES (0, '$interessado','$email','$cpf','$telefone','$cidade','$interesse','$mensagem','$nome','$conteudo','$tipo')";

 mysql_query($qry);

 if(mysql_affected_rows($conn) > 0)
 print "Currículo enviado com sucesso!";
 else
 print "Não foi possível gravar o arquivo na base de dados.";
 }
 else
 print "Não foi possível carregar o arquivo para o servidor.";
```

ele me retorna o erro: **Não foi possível gravar o arquivo na base de dados.**

Comment: Isso não parece ter a ver com banco de dados, você está inserindo um pdf no banco? Em blob é isso? Não da para entender, coloque seu código

Comment: [*`UPLOAD_ERR_OK` Valor: 0; não houve erro, o upload foi bem sucedido.*](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Comment: @AndersonHenrique isso mesmo quero gravar em blob e ele me retorna esse erro

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss ele me retorna o erro e não grava o arquivo em blob

Comment: Use a função [`mysql_error`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-error.php) para exibir algum erro que te ajude em desenvolvimento - deixe estas mensagens *amigáveis* de "não foi possível fazer ..." para o ambiente de produção. Além disso, há uma leitura obrigatória para você: [Por que não devemos usar funções do tipo mysql_*?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/579/5878)

Comment: Apaguei o comentário anterior, pq acho que levaria a alguma confusão sobre o uso técnico, todavia ainda sim recomendo não fazer o upload dos dados diretamente no banco. Vou formular uma resposta.

Comment: Caro @betinhosilva editei a resposta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/322295/3635 - tinha mais coisas para falar, mas acho que iria muito além do perguntando.

Answer (score 2):

Se quer ter uma noção do erro, basta fazer algo como:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO trabalhe (id, nome, email, cpf, telefone, cidade, 
 interesse, mensagem, nome_arquivo, arquivo, tipo) VALUES (0, '$interessado','$email','$cpf','$telefone','$cidade','$interesse','$mensagem','$nome','$conteudo','$tipo')";

mysql_query($qry) or die( mysql_error() );
```

Provavelmente vai retornar algum erro de sintaxe ou vai afirmar que o id igual a zero `0` é errado, sim o id não pode ser zero, aliais se `id` for `AUTOINCREMENT` este campo deveria ser omitido, assim:

```
$qry = "INSERT INTO trabalhe (nome, email, cpf, telefone, cidade, 
 interesse, mensagem, nome_arquivo, arquivo, tipo) VALUES ('$interessado','$email','$cpf','$telefone','$cidade','$interesse','$mensagem','$nome','$conteudo','$tipo')";
```

Outra coisa importante a se dizer, o `addslashes` não é usado para escapar no mysql, o objetivo dele é outro, aliais nenhuma das suas variaveis foi escapada:

```
$interessado    = $_POST["nome"];
$email          = $_POST["email"];
$cpf            = $_POST["cpf"];
$telefone       = $_POST["telefone"];
$cidade         = $_POST["cidade"];
$interesse      = $_POST["interesse"];
$mensagem       = $_POST["msg"];
```

Qualquer caractere nisto pode causar o erro de sintaxe no INSERT do mysql.

Recomendo muito mesmo que atualize os seus scripts para **MYSQLI**, ou seja o banco ainda é o mysql, mas a API de acesso agora é a MYSQLI ou PDO, você escolhe, creio que mysqli lhe será mais fácil e familiar.

Então seguindo os exemplos da doc: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

if (!$link) {
    printf("Can't connect to localhost. Error: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit;
}

//Escapa as variaveis conforme as configurações de conexão
$interessado    = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["nome"]);
$email          = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["email"]);
$cpf            = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["cpf"]);
$telefone       = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["telefone"]);
$cidade         = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["cidade"]);
$interesse      = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["interesse"]);
$mensagem       = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["msg"]);

//Se o arquivo estiver ok o erro é igual a constante UPLOAD_ERR_OK
if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    $arquivo        = $_FILES["arquivo"]["tmp_name"]; 
    $tamanho        = $_FILES["arquivo"]["size"];
    $tipo           = $_FILES["arquivo"]["type"];
    $nome           = $_FILES["arquivo"]["name"];

    $fp = fopen($arquivo, "rb");
    $conteudo = fread($fp, $tamanho);
    $conteudo = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $conteudo);
    fclose($fp); 

    $qry = "INSERT INTO trabalhe (nome, email, cpf, telefone, cidade, 
     interesse, mensagem, nome_arquivo, arquivo, tipo) VALUES ('$interessado','$email','$cpf','$telefone','$cidade','$interesse','$mensagem','$nome','$conteudo','$tipo')";

    //Se funcionar informa quantas linhas foram inseridas (vai retornar "1" sempre/provavelmente)
    if (mysqli_query($link, "CREATE TABLE Language SELECT * from CountryLanguage")) {
        echo 'linhas atualizadas: ', mysqli_affected_rows($link));
    } else {
        //Se falhar informa o erro
        echo 'Erro:', mysqli_error($link)
    }
} else {
     echo 'Erro no upload';
}
```

Claro que eu realmente não recomendo salvar os dados de uma imagem diretamente no banco, seria melhor salvar no disco e colocar o caminho da imagem no banco.

Creio que esta pergunta responde o porque não acho um caminho bom gravar diretamente no banco:

- [É errado gravar byte de imagens no banco de dados?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/12687/3635)

Não estou dizendo que é totalmente errado, só que na maioria dos casos não é um bom caminho.

Se a sua intenção é bloquear o acesso externo aos documentos você pode limitar o acesso a pasta usando um `.htaccess` permitindo somente um php obter o conteudo ou se o objetivo é somente bloquear google e bing de indexarem bastaria usar `robots.txt`:

```
Disallow: /imagens/*
```

Comment: Está dando este erro Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes

Comment: @BetinhoSilva seu MySQL não está configurado para a quantidade de dados que está enviando. Mas isso ja é outro assunto.

Comment: @BetinhoSilva pq precisa inserir imagem direto dentro do banco? Eu pessoalmente acho isso um caminho não muito bom (como citei no ultimo paragrafo da resposta), o melhor seria salvar em uma pasta e só colocar o caminho da pasta no banco, tipo `/imagens/foo.jpg`

Comment: Sobre este erro, leia este post: [Erro 1153 do MySQL: Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37520/70)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento pq o google estava indexando os curriculos da pasta... ai o cliente pediu uma solução e acabei achando esta :D

Comment: @BetinhoSilva mas ai é facil de resolver, essa solução realmente não é boa, com `robots.txt` você poderia bloquear facilmente isto.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento vou gravar em pastas entao... e vamos ver o q dá kkk... mas me explica pq gravar direto no banco é inviável?

Comment: @BetinhoSilva tem uma pergunta inteira dedicada a falar sobre isso, se eu encontrar te mando o link aqui ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento aguardando....

Comment: @BetinhoSilva editei a resposta, veja o final :)